# Method return an interface

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface

**Hi All,**

I'm thinking in this line of code

```
IDataReader myReader = questDatabase.ExecuteReader(getQuest);
```

I'm using DAAB but I can't understand how and what's the meaning of the fact the method ExecuteReader(DbCommand) returns an IDataReader Interface.

**Anyone can Explain, Please**

Comment: I'm learning interfaces and had the exact same question.  Pablito's answer was exactly what I was looking for and confirmed I was building my implementation correctly.  Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It allows you to you DataReader without the need of knowing which type of DataReader you are using (i.e. `SqlDataReader, OleDbDataReader, EtcDataReader`), so if someday you want to change the datareader you are using it won't impact you logic, in other words it gives you abstraction.
For example :

you can use

```
IDbCommand command = GiveMeSomeCommand();
IDataReader r = command.ExecuteReader();
```

without knowing which provider you are using

it can be:

```
private static IDbCommand GiveMeSomeCommand()
{
    return new OleDbCommand();
}
```

or it can be

```
private static IDbCommand GiveMeSomeCommand()
{
    return new SqlCommand();
}
```

or whatever.

EDIT:

You can also use the DBFactories.

```
DbProviderFactory factory = GiveMeSomeFactory();
IDbCommand command = factory.CreateCommand();
IDataReader r = command.ExecuteReader();

//and create more objects
IDataAdapter adapter = factory.CreateDataAdapter();
IDbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
```

and then create your provider in other layer

```
private DbProviderFactory GiveMeSomeFactory()
{
    if(something)
        return SqlClientFactory.Instance;
    else if(somethingElse)
        return OracleFactory.Instance;
    else if(notThisAndNotThat)
        return MySqlFactory.Instance;
    else
        return WhateverFactory.Instance;

}
```

Comment: I Really Thank You ALL, I'm surprising in your dedication, It's grat to be in a comunity like this.

Thanks All

Answer (score 6):

The method will return an object, which is an instance of a class, and that type of class will support `IDataReader`.

The point is, the type of the object isn't important, just the fact that the class implements the interface.

If you're driving a car, you don't need to know if it's a ford, or a toyota, you drive the car the same way.

The driving *interface* is the same, once the car supports the interface, you can drive it.

Ditto with the `IDataReader`, once the class that is returned supports the interface, you can use it.

Answer (score 5):

*"Returns an interface"* really means:

> Returns an instance of some class that implements that interface

In this case, it returns an object very similar to a `SqlDataReader` object, that lets you to execute methods like `Read()` and implements the `IDisposable` and `IDataRecord` interfaces.

Comment: I Really Thank You ALL, I'm surprising in your dedication, It's grat to be in a comunity like this.

Thanks All

Comment: is this a similar concept to polymorphism (ie an Object pointer can point to any reference type that inherits from Object?

Answer (score 4):

It returns an interface because the implementation of the interface isn't important, just the API that the interface provides.

Comment: I Really Thank You ALL, I'm surprising in your dedication, It's grat to be in a comunity like this.

Thanks All

Answer (score 3):

It's not returning an Interface per se, but instead an object that supports that interface.

Comment: I Really Thank You ALL, I'm surprising in your dedication, It's grat to be in a comunity like this.

Thanks All

Answer (score 3):

It returns an object that implements this particular interface, and that's all you really care about. The object is a `IDataReader`, and can perform all the methods `IDataReader` has.

Comment: I Really Thank You ALL, I'm surprising in your dedication, It's grat to be in a comunity like this.

Thanks All

Comment: That's what I like about StackOverflow :p