# interface as return type

Tags: c#, interface

Can interface be a return type of a function. If yes then whats the advantage. e.g. is the following code correct where array of interface is being returned.

```
public interface Interface
{
    int Type { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}

public override Interface[] ShowValue(int a)
{
.
.

}
```

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) Because it allows polymorphic behaviour.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - List<T> or IList<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400135/c-sharp-listt-or-ilistt)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List<T> or IList<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400135/listt-or-ilistt)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, you can return an interface.

Let's say classes `A` and `B` each implement interface `Ic`:

```
public interface Ic
{
    int Type { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}

public class A : Ic
{
     .
     .
     .
}

public class B : Ic
     .
     .
     .
}

public Ic func(bool flag)
{
     if (flag)
         return new A();
       return new B();

}
```

In this example `func` is like factory method — it can return different objects!

Comment: Can I interpret the return of interface as "return an object that has implemented Ic"? It is very confusing to me as we can not create an instance of interface but we can return one.

Comment: It's because an interface is a "Type" description like an int, or class, but an interface can have multiple implementation of it's type. 

Thus when you are returning the "interface" you are actually returning the implementation of said interface. 

if you do a "IExample example = new ExampleImpl();"
adn then "example .GetType() == typeof(ExampleImpl)" this will return true. but false for other implementations of said interface. Does that make sense to you @Yu Zhang?

Answer (score 26):

Yes an `interface` is a very valid return value. Remember, you're not returning the definition of the interface, but rather an ***instance of an implementation*** of that interface.

The benefit is very clear, consider the following code:

```
public interface ICar
{
    string Make { get; }
}

public class Malibu : ICar
{
    public string Make { get { return "Chevrolet"; } }
}

public class Mustang : ICar
{
    public string Make { get { return "Ford"; } }
}
```

now you could return a number of different `ICar` instances that have their own respective values.

But, the primary reason for using interfaces is so that they can be shared amongst assemblies in a well-known contract so that when you pass somebody an `ICar`, they don't know anything about it, but they know it has a `Make`. Further, they can't execute anything against it except the public interface. So if `Mustang` had a `public` member named `Model` they couldn't get to that unless it was in the interface.

Comment: It is very confusing to me as we cannot create an instance of an interface but we can return an instance of an interface. Did you mean return an instance of an object that has implemented of an interface?

Comment: @YuZhang you're right. You can't return an instance of an interface, and this guy's answer is wrong.  

You can't return an instance of an interface, because an interface is not a type. 

An interface is not a type because it does not have any associated data.

An interface in this context is like a predicate that encapsulates any possible type that defines the methods declared in the interface. 

When you "return an interface" you're really defining a constraint on that method that says the return type must have certain methods defined.

Comment: @YuZhang I have modified the language, but we're probably being a little pedantic because it's effectively the same language.

Comment: @AdamVanOijen I have modified the language, but we're probably being a little pedantic because it's effectively the same language.

Answer (score 10):

Yes it can.

The benefit is that you can abstract the return (and input) types.

```
public interface IFruit{ }

public class Apple: IFruit{}

public class Pear: IFruit{}

...

public function IFruit SelectRandomFromBasket(Basket<IFruit> basket){
  // this function can return Apple, Pear
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes it's possible, and it's a good thing for public functions.

For the **why** part of your question, I won't copy paste other people answers, so please refer to existing answers, for example:

- [List<T> or IList<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400135/c-sharp-listt-or-ilistt)
- [Method return an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511248/method-return-an-interface)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3564291/870604

Comment: if you've found other questions/answers on the same topic, wouldn't it be better to [close as duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) instead of linking to other posts?

Comment: @ChaseFlorell Sure. Actually I was writing my own answer and *then* realized this might be answered already, so I cleared my own text and added some helpful links instead... but voting to close as duplicate anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I will answer your question in golang perspective where we can use interface as a return type that means you can return any datatype e.g int, float, string etc.

interface = any datatype

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func any (u interface{}) interface{} {
    fmt.Printf("Type: %T\n",u)
    return u
}

func main(){
    fmt.Println("value: ",any(5))
    fmt.Println(any("testing"))
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELbao.png)

Comment: Hello, this question is tagged C#, not Go.

Comment: Thanks! #Paul, to be honest i didn't observe the tag. But the question has relation with golang and will help users of golang and goswagger... while understanding return type and handlers.

Comment: Agree with @Artaghal. Although the question is tagged to c#, it answers the first question(`Can interface be a return type of a function`). This might not be true for other languages(if a function could return an interface) but it is true for both Golang and C#.