# In C# how can a function have an IEnumerable Interface as a return type?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield-return

So I understand that this function allows the result to be iterated over with a foreach statement, but I don't understand how the return type can be an interface.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Func1(int number, int exponent)
{
    int exponentNum = 0;
    int numberResult = 1;

    while (exponentNum < exponent)
    {
        numberResult *= number;
        exponentNum++;

        yield return numberResult;
    }
}
```

On the MSDN documentation it states:

> The interface defines only the signature
>
> • An interface can't be instantiated directly. Its members are implemented by any class or struct that implements the interface.

So if Interfaces contain only method signatures, then how can one possibly be the return type of a function? and how does this function enable the foreach statement?

Comment: You can return anything that implements `IEnumerable<int>`

Comment: So what IS an interface for, if as you suggest it can't exist and hence can't be used for anything? Clearly, that's not the case. Concrete classes can *implement* an interface. If an object implements `IFoo`, you can pass a reference to it as `IFoo`. That's what they're for. In this case, with yield return, the compiler magically creates a concrete class that implements it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392224/interface-as-return-type

Comment: Perhaps you might want to look at what `yield` actually does. I reckon that might be part of your confusion.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I know classes can implement an interface but MSDN says classes "...can provide an implementation of an interface only one time and only if the class declares the interface as part of the definition of the class (class ClassName : InterfaceName)". But my function is in a class that does not contain the " : InterfaceName" part. My class looks like this: "class Class1 {...}". So according to that, my function is not implementing an interface.

Comment: OH OK I see what you're thinking. But that's not the deal. The class your method is a member of has nothing to do with it. It's totally unrelated. For instance, you can write a method that returns `String`. That doesn't mean your class has to inherit from `String`. Your function has nothing to do with implementing the interface. The object it *returns* has to implement the interface.

Comment: ...However! With `yield return`, the concrete class implementing the iteration is actually created by the compiler where you never see it, which doesn't help clarify matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you can return anything that implements the interface, and the calling code need not care what the concrete implementation is, but it can use any of the functions of the returned object that are declared in the interface.

It's one way that you have of creating standard interfaces between parts of your code, while allowing the internal implementation to be changed without affecting everything else.

So for instance you could return a `List<int>` from your function, and it would be valid.

Your function uses `yield return`, which means it will return each element of the iteration one at a time and implicitly create the `IEnumerable<int>` for you, rather than you creating an explicit list object.  Internally it will create some concrete type that implements `IEnumerable` and return that, but the calling code will just see it as an `IEnumerable` because that's the return type of the method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx gives you more details and also an example very similar to the function you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

If the return type is an interface, any concrete class that implements the interface can be returned from the function.

As a simple example, you could return `List<int>`, which implements `IEnumerable<int>`.